# How retrieve all object that are present at least one time in all array of array?

Tags: javascript

I have a multiple array of array of objects:

```
var lists = [];

lists.push([{label: 'a'}, {label: 'b'}, {label: 'c'}]);
lists.push([{label: 'b'}, {label: 'a'}, {label: 'e'}]);
lists.push([{label: 'a'}, {label: 'e'}, {label: 'b'}]);
```

I want retrieve all object that are present at least one time in all lists, in this case: `{label: 'a'}` and `{label: 'b'}`

this is my code:

```js
var lists = [];

lists.push([{label: 'a'}, {label: 'b'}, {label: 'c'}]);
lists.push([{label: 'b'}, {label: 'a'}, {label: 'e'}]);
lists.push([{label: 'a'}, {label: 'e'}, {label: 'b'}]);


var tmp = [];
for(var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++){
  var list = lists[i];
  for(var j = 0; j < list.length; j++){
    var obj = list[j];
    if( !tmp[obj.label] ){
        obj.inList = [];
        tmp[obj.label] = obj;
    } 
    tmp[obj.label].inList[i] = true;
  }
}

var result = [];
for(var key in tmp){
    result.push(tmp[key]);
}

var result = result.filter(function(obj){
  return Object.keys(obj.inList).length === lists.length;
});

// expected result [{label: 'a'}, {label: 'b'}]
console.log(result);
```

My code works, but has bad performance with large array. There is a fastest way?

Comment: Did you try with `reduce` and `filter`? It will be something like `someArray.reduce( (acc, curr) => { acc.concat(curr.filter( someCondition))}, [])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to iterate over each of the lists and increment a counter per label each time an object is seen. Then, once all of the lists are processed, any label whose count is equal to the number of lists must be present in all of them.

For example:

```
function OmnipresentObjectTracker(key) {
  var arrayCount = 0
  var presentCounts = {}
  var objectsByKeyname = {}

  this.add = function(arr) {
    arrayCount++
    var alreadyCounted = {}
    arr.forEach(function(obj) {
      if (key in obj) {
        const value = obj[key]
        objectsByKeyname[value] = obj
        if (!alreadyCounted[value]) {
          presentCounts[value] = (presentCounts[value]||0) + 1
          alreadyCounted[value] = true;
        }
      }
    })
  }

  this.getObjects = function() {
    return Object.keys(presentCounts).reduce(function(memo, k) {
      if (presentCounts[k] === arrayCount) {
        memo.push(objectsByKeyname[k])
      }
      return memo
    }, [])
  }
}

var oot = new OmnipresentObjectTracker('label')

oot.add([{label: 'a'}, {label: 'b'}, {label: 'c'}]);
oot.getObjects() // => [{label: "a"}, {label: "b"}, {label: "c"}]

oot.add([{label: 'b'}, {label: 'a'}, {label: 'e'}]);
oot.add([{label: 'a'}, {label: 'e'}, {label: 'b'}]);
oot.getObjects() // => [{label: "a"}, {label: "b"}]

oot.add([{label: 'a'}, {label: 'a'}])
oot.getObjects() // => [{label: "a"}]
```

Comment: this would fail, if a list contain duplicate labels.

Comment: @amrendersingh yes, great observation, I've modified it so that it only increments the _first_ time it sees the label per added list.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate once over all the Arrays and create a map. Map each label to a set which contains index of all the subarrays in which that label is present. If `set` size  is `=` to  size of the parent array (`lists` in your case) that means the label is present in all the sub arrays, since set would not contain no duplicate entries and size is equal to `lists.length` that means the label was present in all the subarrays(this certain as we add the index of each subarray to the set) .Try the following:

```js
var lists = [];

lists.push([{label: 'a'}, {label: 'b'}, {label: 'c'}]);
lists.push([{label: 'b'}, {label: 'a'}, {label: 'e'}]);
lists.push([{label: 'a'}, {label: 'e'}, {label: 'b'}]);

let map = {};

lists.forEach((list, index)=>{
  list.forEach((label)=>{
    map[label.label]  = map[label.label] || new Set();
    map[label.label].add(index);
  });
});

let result = [];
Object.keys(map).forEach((key)=>{
  if(map[key].size == lists.length)
    result.push({label : key});
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#reduce` to add all unique keys with its count in an object accumulator. Then using `array#filter` filter out all keys whose count is equal to your array length and then regenerate your array of object.

```js
var lists = [];
lists.push([{label: 'a'}, {label: 'b'}, {label: 'c'}]);
lists.push([{label: 'b'}, {label: 'a'}, {label: 'e'}]);
lists.push([{label: 'a'}, {label: 'e'}, {label: 'b'}]);

var common = lists.reduce((r, a) => {
  var unique = [...new Set(a.map(({label}) => label))];
  unique.forEach(v => {
    v in r ? r[v]++: r[v] = 1;
  });
  return r;
},{});

var result = Object.keys(common).filter(k => common[k] === lists.length).map(label => ({label}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd change it up a little and discard the lements not found in each array. That way, your iteration count is reduced with every array. Like so:

```js
var lists = [];

lists.push([{label: 'a'}, {label: 'b'}, {label: 'c'}]);
lists.push([{label: 'b'}, {label: 'a'}, {label: 'e'}]);
lists.push([{label: 'a'}, {label: 'e'}, {label: 'b'}]);

var final = [];

// Add every element from the first list
for(var e in lists[0]) {
    final.push(lists[0][e]);
}

// Iterate every list item in the main array
for(var list in lists) {
    // Iterate only the remaining elements in the final array
    for(var f in final) {
        var exists = false; // Sentinel that checks if the element exists
        
        for(var e in lists[list]) {
            if(final[f].label == lists[list][e].label) {
                exists = true; // Change the flag if the element is found
            }
        }
        
        // If the element was not found, remove the element from the final array
        if(!exists) {
            final.splice(f,1);
        }
    }
}

console.log(final);

/*
[
  {
    "label": "a"
  },
  {
    "label": "b"
  }
]
*/
```